# Trying to read a text file into classes then cycle through

Tags: c#, io

Hi am a fairly novice when it comes to c# and I have being trying to read out a text file then splitting it into sections with classes but have trouble with where to declare them an then how to cycle through the records. here's my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Assignment_3
{
     public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string s;
        string ss;
        int i = 1;
        string infilename;
        int num;
        SortedList sList = new SortedList();
        int x = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            student myself = new student();
            infilename = "text.txt";
            StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(infilename);
            sList.Clear();
            while ((s = sr1.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] strs = s.Split(',');

                myself.firstname = strs[0];
                myself.middlename = strs[1];
                myself.surname = strs[2];
                myself.dob = DateTime.Parse(strs[3]);
                myself.dob.ToString(strs[3]);
                myself.sex = strs[4];
                ss = myself.dob.ToString("u");
                sList.Add(myself.firstname, myself);

            }
             sr1.Close();
             num = sList.Count;
             student[] pArray = new student[num];
             string[] keys = new string[num];



             foreach (DictionaryEntry d in sList)
             {
                 keys[x] = (string)d.Key;
                 pArray[x] = (student)d.Value;
                 x++;
             }
             if (i == 0)
             {lblmessage.Text = "Already at the first record."; i = 1; }
             if (i == num)
             {lblmessage.Text = "Already at the last record.";i = num-1; }

             lbllastname.Text = pArray[i].surname;
             lblfirstname.Text = pArray[i].firstname;
             lblsecondname.Text = pArray[i].middlename;
             lbldob.Text = pArray[i].dob.ToString();
             lblsex.Text = pArray[i].sex;

        }

        private void btnlast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i = num;

        }
        private void btnfirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i = 0;
        }

        private void btnnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i++;

        }

        private void btnprev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i--;
        }


    }
}
```

and my class file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Assignment_3
{
    class student
    {
        public string firstname;
        public string middlename;
        public string surname;
        public DateTime dob;
        public string sex;
    }
}
```

anyone have any ideas where am going wrong?? I have no errors but find that the text fields do not update with the new record's and then when stepped through the array class holds the correct amount of records and fields, I feel its going to be something very obvious put cant put my finger on it.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You've not told us what errors you are receiving and where?

Comment: create a new student for every line you read IN the while loop: myself = new student();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create new instance of `student` inside `for` loop. Because at the moment you have only one instance of student class and all items in `SortedList` are pointing to same object.